# Display shapeFile on leaflet map using an uploaded file.zip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I'm trying to display a shape file from Brazil on my leaflet map, this shape file is inside a .zip that contains: .dbf, .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .shp and .shx files. To do that, I'm using: https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile

I have the .zip file at my local computer so I simply made:

HTML

```
<button ng-click="addShape()"> Brasil Shape File </button>
```

JS

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-12.85, -50.09], 4);
$scope.addShape = function () {
    var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('scripts/ShapeFiles/Brasil.zip');
    shpfile.addTo(mymap);
}
```

Now I want to make the user upload the .zip to show it on the map exactly like whats happening here:
http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55

But I can't figure this out... All I have found on the internet is posting the .zip file to an url. I need to use the file right after the user "uploaded" it to the browser.

On the code bellow the user can upload some file and POST it, I tried to console.log the supposed objects that contains the .zip file before sending it but I couldn't find it inside the objects:

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
   <div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
      <input type="file" ng-model-instant id="fileToUpload" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" />
   </div>
   <input type="button" ng-click="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
</body>
```

JS

```
scope.setFiles = function(element) {
scope.$apply(function(scope) {
  console.log('files:', element.files);
  // Turn the FileList object into an Array
    scope.files = []
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
      scope.files.push(element.files[i])
    }
  scope.progressVisible = false
  });
};

scope.uploadFile = function() {
    var fd = new FormData()
    for (var i in scope.files) {
        fd.append("uploadedFile", scope.files[i])
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false)
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false)
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false)
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false)
    xhr.open("POST", "/fileupload")
    scope.progressVisible = true
    xhr.send(fd)
}
```

source fiddle: [danielzen](http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/)

On this exemple, inside the functions 'setFiles' and 'uploadFile', when I console.log(fd) I get: `fd: [object FormData]` and console.log(element.files):

```
element.files[0] File {name: "Brasil (1).zip", lastModified: 1492436239000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 17 2017 10:37:19 GMT-0300 (BRT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5988862…}
```

But I can't find the original .zip file that was uploaded, maybe because this is not the right way to do it...
If someone knows a way to get this .zip file or have access to this [example](http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/) source and can share with me I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using an arrayBuffer for the shapefile as it is specified [here](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile). I figured that out reading about [this](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/issues/22) issue.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 800px;float: left;">

</div>
<form action='#' onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type='file' id='fileinput'>
    <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='loadFile();'>
</form>
```

JS

```
function loadFile() {

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (!input.files[0]) {
        bodyAppend("p", "Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
        file = input.files[0];

        fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = receiveBinary;
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    function receiveBinary() {
        result = fr.result
        var shpfile = new L.Shapefile(result);
        shpfile.addTo(mymap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, excellent answer, it really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

I use angular 12... and I can upload file with  Shapefile.js https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js

You can see my code in https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2141645